# How to set perScenarioTimeout into uftScenarioLoad?

Tags: jenkins

I'am trying to run uftScenarioLoad on jenkins but it does not allow perScenarioTimeout parameter based on the documentation:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/hp-application-automation-tools-plugin/#uftscenarioload-run-uft-scenario

My pipeline looks like next:

```
uftScenarioLoad archiveTestResultsMode: 'ALWAYS_ARCHIVE_TEST_REPORT', fsTimeout: '600', fsUftRunMode: testsRunMode, testPaths: testPath
```

I found that class is calling two other classes `RunFromFileBuilder` and `RunResultRecorder`, https://github.com/hpsa/hpe-application-automation-tools-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hp/application/automation/tools/pipelineSteps/UftScenarioLoadStep.java

When I replace my previous command with separated commands:

```
step([$class: 'RunFromFileBuilder', fsTimeout: '600', fsUftRunMode: 'Normal', fsTests: '''Host_Validation''', perScenarioTimeOut: '30'])
step([$class: 'RunResultRecorder', archiveTestResultsMode: 'ALWAYS_ARCHIVE_TEST_REPORT'])
```

But I get the next error:

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob cannot be cast to hudson.model.Project
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob cannot be cast to hudson.model.Project
    at com.microfocus.application.automation.tools.results.RunResultRecorder.perform(RunResultRecorder.java:1401)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```